# VB .NET - datatable.SELECT filter problem

Tags: .net, vb.net

Have datatable loaded from SQL.  6 columns.  One column UNITNO (nchar10).  Other columns mix of (nchar10) and (varchar50).  Working against .NET framework 4.5. VS 2015

```
Dim shw1() As Data.DataRow
shw1 = DataSet1.Shipments.Select("UnitNo = 015785")
```

Select statement has worked great for months.  Until value of UNITNO hit 015784 or 15785. Took a row passed that SELECT worked correctly and changed the UNITNO column to 015784 get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Min (44) must be less than or equal to max (-1) in a Range object.
  Source=System.Data
```

If UNITNO is 015785 get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Min (45) must be less than or equal to max (-1) in a Range object.
  Source=System.Data
```

Min value in the error message changes.  Appears that my SELECT parameter is being misinterpreted.  I've tried every possible combination of quotes to no effect.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: What's the result if you enclose the parameter value in quotes `Select("UnitNo = '015784'")`?

Comment: Tried that.  Same error.

Comment: If UnitNo is nchar(10) then shouldn't you have 10 characters in the numeric value? 015785 is not 10 characters.  So it needs padding out appropriately and surrounding with single quotes.